# Real-time spectrum analyzer with API

Tags: c++, spectrum, analyzer, fft, signal-processing

I'm looking for a C or C++ API that will give me real-time spectrum analysis of a waveform on Windows.

I'm not **entirely** sure how large a sample window it should need to determine frequency content, but the smaller the better.  For example, if it can work with a 0.5 second long sample and determine frequency content to the Hz, that would be wicked-awesome.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to extract semi-precise frequencies from a WAV file using Fourier Transforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881583/how-to-extract-semi-precise-frequencies-from-a-wav-file-using-fourier-transforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) a few years ago. It is supposedly fast (though I didn't use it for anything real-time myself) and was certainly pretty easy to use, even on Windows.

Regarding the window size, see [the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist-Shannon_sampling_theorem).

(I imagine there are other issues involved when using a window on the data, particularly for low frequencies, but I'm no expert and I couldn't find any useful-looking info about this, so maybe I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

For details of how to generate a power spectrum and how to determine frequency resolution of same, please see my answer to this question: [How to extract semi-precise frequencies from a WAV file using Fourier Transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881583/how-to-extract-semi-precise-frequencies-from-a-wav-file-using-fourier-transforms/2885833#2885833)

Comment: Yes yo, that's a great answer!